# Appium When I divide by 11 its a pass when should fail

Tags: java, selenium, appium

num1 * 12 = num2. How come when I divide num2 by 11. It still passes it won't fail. I do equals total with numonenum. If I divide by 12 which should be pass and when I divide by 11 its still a pass. numonenum = $2.5, numtwonum = $30. numone and numtwo is a pageobject.

```
public boolean num1num2() {
    try{


    String num1 = numone.getText();
    String num2 = numtwo.getText();

    //Converting String to Integer to Divide Months

    double numonenum = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    double numtwonum = Integer.parseInt(num2);

    double total = numtwonum / 11;
    System.out.println(total);
    System.out.println(numonenum);
    Assert.assertEquals(numonenum, total, "Total Matches numonenum");

    return true;

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    return false;
}
    }
```

Comment: `numonenum = 2.5` - that cannot be true, since you assign an `int` (`Integer.parseInt(num1)`) to `numonenum`. Perhaps you should use `Double.parseDouble`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test didn't arrive to the assertion, `Integer.parseInt("2.5");` will throw `NumberFormatException`, which will be caught by the `catch` block. Use

```
num1 = num1.replace("$", "");
double numonenum = Double.parseDouble(num1);
```

Comment: Thanks how would round up within .8 its a pass anything higher a fail.

Comment: The test still passes when you divide by 11 don' know why?

Comment: I get this error when I run without try catch. java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$2.5"